# Excluded point topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, vector-spaces, geometric-topology, topological-vector-spaces

The real numbers with $\tau=\{G:0\notin G\}\cup \{R\}$ be a topological spaces. What is the Int(Q) and Cl(Q)?
I know the rational number Q is not open in $\tau$ since $0\in Q$.

Comment: "I know that $\Bbb Q$ is not open... since $0\in\Bbb Q$".. Then how about $\Bbb Q-\{0\}$? In order to find the closure notice that $0\notin\Bbb Q^{\complement}$

Comment: means that $Q^C$ is open and $Q-\{0\}$ is open?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. And $\Bbb Q-\{0\}$ is evidently the largest open subset of $\Bbb Q$, so is $\mathsf{int}(\Bbb Q)$. Further if $\Bbb Q^{\complement}$ is open then $\Bbb Q$ is closed hence coincides with its closure.

Comment: I see. Thanks for helping me, I am short on information about this space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closure of $\Bbb Q$ is the smallest closed set containing it. $\Bbb Q$ is itself closed as its complement does *not* contain $0$. So the closure is just $\Bbb Q$.

The interior is the largest open subset and $\Bbb Q \setminus \{0\}$ is that set (it’s open by construction and the only larger subset is the set itself which is *not* open).

So in general $\operatorname{int}(A)$ is $A$ if $0 \notin A$ and $A\setminus \{0\}$ otherwise. Only $A=\Bbb R$ is an exception…